# One line drawn longer than another line on the same Cartesian plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Why are the two lines drawn to different lengths?  The slanted line should be shortened a bit - maybe by 2ex - and the vertical line should be lengthened to obtain the same height that the slanted line obtains.

How do I get the equation for the slanted line on the opposite side?  The place it is now makes it look like I am labeling the curve y=(3/2)x + 5/2.

If I want a little more of the graph above the x-axis to be drawn, what should I change in the code?  `ymax=25` instead of `ymax=15`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,
    domain=-15:15, samples=101,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-15,ymax=15,
    restrict y to domain=-20:20,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty}
]
\addplot[samples=251,domain=-25:1.5] {(3*x^2+5*x)/(2*x-3)};
\addplot[samples=251,domain=1.5:25] {(3*x^2+5*x)/(2*x-3)} node[above,pos=0.85]{$\scriptstyle{y}=\frac{3x^{2}+5x}{2x-3}$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex] {(3/2)*x+5/2} node [pos=0.15, anchor=south, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$y=\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{5}{2}$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex] (1.5,x) node [pos=0.15, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=\frac{3}{2}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Something like `node[below]` instead of above?

Comment: You can get the equation of the slanted line the way you want by changing `anchor=south` to `anchor=north`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-15,xmax=15,
    samples=101,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-15,ymax=15,
    restrict y to domain=-20:25,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
]
\addplot[samples=251,domain=-25:1.5] {(3*x^2+5*x)/(2*x-3)};
\addplot[samples=251,domain=1.5:15] {(3*x^2+5*x)/(2*x-3)} node[above right,anchor=south west,pos=0.95]{$\scriptstyle{y}=\frac{3x^{2}+5x}{2x-3}$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,domain=-13:10] {(3/2)*x+5/2} node [pos=0.15, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$y=\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{5}{2}$};
\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,domain=-17:17.5] (1.5,x) node [pos=0.15, anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, sloped] {$x=\frac{3}{2}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some explanations:

You can add the proper domain to the dashed plots. For the slanted line, let us say we fix `,domain=-13:10`. Then the maximum and minimum values of `y` are `17.5` and `-17` respectively. Noe we fix theses values for `y` in the vertical dashed line as `domain=-17:17.5` in the coordinate `{1.5,x}`.

To bring the label below for the slanted line change the anchor to `anchor=north,`.

To extend the upper curve you have to change the values in `restrict y to domain=-20:25,`. Change the `ymax` and `xmax`, `ymin` and `xmin` values accordingly so as to get the axis line length suitably. (Or change the value of `abs=1cm` in `enlargelimits`).